# Match Function returning Run-time error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with unique values. I populate a listbox on a userform with those values and return data from another column to a label caption when a value from the listbox is clicked with the following code:

```
With Table
    Set rngNum = .ListColumns(.ListColumns(strNum).Range.column).DataBodyRange
    Set rngVal = .ListColumns(.ListColumns(strVal).Range.column).DataBodyRange
End With
With Worksheet
        strResult = wf.Index(.Range(rngVal.address), wf.Match(lstVal.List(lstVal.ListIndex), .Range(rngNum.address), 0)) --Error occurs here!
End With
    lblDescription.Caption = strResult
```

The code has worked perfectly for several months until recently I get a `Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class` on the line noted above.

The error occurs when I click on certain values in the listbox. Most of the values in the range are numbers stored as text but there a few that are not. Originally, I thought that was the problem. But, strangely, of the values that are not stored as text, one of them gives the error and the other doesn't. The table is exported from the Internet. Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you need additional information. Thank you!

Comment: Not really sure what to say other than that the value in your list doesn't match the one on the sheet. You are best placed to figure out why with some debugging... ;)

Comment: To make it so the code will not stop when it does not find the value do not use WorksheetFunction.  use `Application.Match(...` and declare strResult as a variant.  This will allow the error to pass into the variable.  Then you can test whether the variable is an error or not before assigning it to the caption.

Comment: I found the error. Some of the cells in the range had leading spaces. But the spaces do not remain when they are loaded into the listbox. When it tries to match the listbox value to the value in the range it errors because the range value has a leading space but the listbox value does not. I'll need a different approach. Thanks!

Comment: use `Trim()` to remove the space

Comment: @Raystafarian The trim function will not work because I am putting the range of data into a listbox and the listbox removes the spaces. Therefore, when I lookup the value I click on in the listbox it does not find it because I am trying to find the listbox value (NO leading space) in the range (leading space).

Comment: I'm saying trim the range - why do you need leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I figured you meant that after posting but I tried that, too. I must have done something wrong.